# How to update old CAPTCHA to use reCAPTCHA V2

Tags: 7, captcha

I am very new to drupal I am trying to update a drupal site to reCAPTCHA V2 but I can't figure out how to. I know I need a new site key and secret key which I have gotten; but how do I actually make the CAPTCHA module update so I can put in my new keys. And so I can get the new reCAPTCHA check boxes instead of the images. I am using Drupal 7. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just update module via update modules page:
Your_site/admin/reports/updates/update

Follow steps and update DB.

Go to modules page and check configuration for recaptcha, there you'll put your new keys (got from https://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Note: If you update module files using FTP, remember to run update.php script.